# Why was this edit rejected even with time consuming change

Tags: discussion

[If variable is in db then stop- if variable is not- then enter it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803541/if-variable-is-in-db-then-stop-if-variable-is-not-then-enter-it)

I spent around 3 minutes, not too long, reformatting the code. It is all spaced out, I got rid of the extra tabs.

Yeah you can read it as is, but those tabs weren't needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9646406 "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"

Comment: Reviewers don't take how much time an edit takes to implement into consideration when accepting or rejecting edits.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan right, really I was just adding that to beat the "title already exists" thing. The reason I asked was I spaced out all of the code, and formatted it correctly. In turn, my edit was rejected, and one with the code all garbaged on a few lines was accepted.